# Android Sample Widget SimpleWiktionary does not update

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, wiktionary

I am trying to wrap my head around Android Widgets, using the sample provided here: http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/

I have corrected the strings.xml but the plugin will not work properly, neither on the emulator nor on the actual phone. It installs fine, but it never updates.

But at least on the simulator i get some DDMS output, telling me, that the API-response could not be parsed, so I assume, that the Wiktionary API has probably changed.

However, on my phone, the  public void onUpdate(...) method doesn't even seem to get called at all when I install the Widget. I have inserted Log.i(...) lines for debugging and while they all show up when I use the Widget on the emulator, none of them seem to come up when it actually runs on the phone.

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S II running android 2.3 but that hardly matters I think.

has anybody encountered this before and knows anything that might help?

**EDIT** I was told it might be a permissions issue, but could not verify this.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Just in case anybody else ever comes across this. There is a strange thing with android widgets when the throw an exception... just uninstalling isn't always enough one hast to restart the phone.

Can not explain why that is but it always did the trick.